# How can I locate this element on selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx0rR.png)

This object has a name and a value. The name is not unique.

I tried locating with the name but failed due to the other object above that has the same name.
How can i solve this problem? please help me out

Answer (score 0):

you can use contains if you're name is not unique

a good example:

```
//tagname[@value='valuetext']
```

above is xpath if name is not unique then you can use value like this

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element with type radio and value 3 with the following x-path:

//input[@type='radio' and @value='3']